# Remove files with match only from some subdirectories

Tags: bash, grep, find, rm, cygwin

I have a directory with several subdirectories; in each of these, I have some files. I want to perform a `grep` only for some subdirectories to find those files that match the query and remove them; something like  `grep -rl --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2 HUMAN . | rm`, but I'd prefer not to parse the `stdin` from `grep`.

I think I have to combine `find` and `rm`, but I don't know how.

Moreover, it seems that (at least here in Cygwin), I cannot do --exclude-dir={dir1, dir2}, I have to split them. This is a minor problem, but does someone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot do"? `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}` works fine for me in `bash`, just remove the space after the comma.

Comment: Using `find` you can reference one file using `{}` within the `-exec` option, eg: `find . -type f -name *.jar -exec ls -l {} \;` searches for all jar-Files and executes a `ls -l ` for each file. *Disclaimer*: I tried it with CentOS, not with cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -rlZ --exclude-dir=dir1 --exclude-dir=dir2 HUMAN . |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

If you want `find` to do the directory traversal:

```
find . -type d \( -name dir1 -o -name dir2 \) -prune -o \
  -type f -exec grep -lZ HUMAN {} + |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Portably/standardly, that would have to be:

```
find . -type d \( -name dir1 -o -name dir2 \) -prune -o \
  -type f -exec grep -q HUMAN {} \; -exec rm -f {} +
```

but that means running one `grep` per file.

For `--exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}` to work, you need a shell with brace expansion support like csh, tcsh, ksh, zsh, bash or fish.