# mkdir with seq command problem

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, mkdir, seq

I need to make 5 directories (name1, name2, name3, name4, name5) by command line using `mkdir` and `seq`.

If I use:

```
mkdir name{`seq -s , 1 5`}
```

It results in one directory: `name{1,2,3,4,5}`

What command should I use instead?

Comment: In Bash you can say `for d in $(seq 5); do mkdir name$d; done`. Read the manual page for your shell; brace expansion happens *before* command substitution. P.S. Are you *sure* that your shell does brace expansion?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please indicate it by clicking the checkmark next to it; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
seq 1 42 | mkdir name{1..5}
```

Or, if you don't need the answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything, drop the `seq` and let bash's brace expansion the the work by itself:

```
mkdir name{1..5}
```

But, if you really need to use `seq` because this is homework:

```
mkdir $(seq -f "name%d" 5)
```

Comment: In case any readers are confused: `seq 1 42 | mkdir name{1..5}` accomplishes the same thing as `mkdir name{1..5}` because the `mkdir` command does not read from [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), so the sequence of numbers `seq` produces is simply ignored. It's a clever way of *technically* using the `seq` command, to comply with contrived requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't just want [to use brace expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398316/11938) (also see below), you might  consider:

```bash
seq 5 | xargs -I N mkdir nameN
```

That creates `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, `name4`, and `name5`. It works even if your shell does not support brace expansion (but `bash` does). The `xargs` command builds and runs commands. That specific `xargs` command runs commands like `mkdir nameN`, but with `N` replaced with each word of the input (which is piped in from `seq`). Run `man xargs` or read [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) for more information on the `-I` option.

If this is for a homework assignment, perhaps you are not allowed to use a third command (`xargs`). But in "real life," you're less likely to have such a restriction. Furthermore, if you're doing this for learning purposes, it's an opportunity to learn the `xargs` command--if you don't already know it--which is useful in a variety of situations.

You can also use a shell loop, as [AlexP suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398293/mkdir-with-seq-command-problem#comment711163_398293) (`for d in $(seq 5); do mkdir name$d; done`). That [`for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) uses the `$(` `)` syntax to perform [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) in order to obtain the list `1 2 3 4 5` from `seq`, then uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (`$d`) to form the directory name in each `mkdir` command.

You should be aware that all those methods rely on the absence of whitespace in the directory names, although it is possible to modify them so that they do not.

But you're using `bash` and, like [many shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269702/remove-files-with-match-only-from-some-subdirectories/269713#269713), it supports [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion). Now, maybe you need your script to be [portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming) to shells that don't (such as [`dash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)). If that's what you need, you should not use brace expansion at all. Otherwise, you should **follow [Jeff Schaller's recommendation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398316/11938) of simply writing `mkdir name{1..5}`**.

Comment: According to a quick search here, several other shells support brace expansion: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269713/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, many shells support brace expansion (but not all). Do you think my answer makes it sound like `bash` is the only one? If so, I'd be pleased to reword it; if not, I'll probably avoid making it any more complicated than it already is.

Comment: Maybe it's the way I'm reading the very last sentence. It seems less likely that they'll run into a shell that doesn't support it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller You're right, it was potentially confusing. I've reworked that paragraph to make it clearer. As for how likely one is to run into a shell that doesn't support brace expansion, it's actually quite common these days on Debian and its derivatives, since for some years `/bin/sh` [has been `dash`](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) rather than `bash`. On the other hand, *my guess* is that being on a system that has no Bourne-style shell *installed and usable* that supports brace expansion is probably pretty rare today, aside from very minimal BusyBox-based systems.